# How I can sort these two files with a specific pattern?

Tags: bash, loops, awk

I've got two files like:

```
cat file 1
C             18     -2.182951850        -0.000000000        -6.517815410
C             20     -4.127401075         0.000000000        -0.446529291
C             22     -3.314258919        -2.494999886       -15.624910016
C             24     -6.071850300         0.000000000         5.624757806
C             26     -2.023950100         0.000000000         5.624757806
C             28     -4.286402584        -0.000000000       -12.589102506
C             30     -6.230851809        -0.000000000        -6.517815410
C             32     -0.079500634         0.000000000        -0.446529291
..            ..     ............         ...........        ............
cat file 2
O             34     -1.393125174        -0.640765928        -5.738276269
O             36     -3.337574640        -0.640765928         0.333010828
O             38     -2.524270589         1.854234106       -14.845370570
O             40     -5.282024106        -0.640765928         6.404297925
O             42     -2.182951850         1.281531856        -6.517815410
O             44     -4.127401075         1.281531856        -0.446529291
O             46     -3.314258919        -1.213468178       -15.624910016
O             48     -6.071850300         1.281531856         5.624757806
O             50     -2.972778044        -0.640765928        -7.297355528
O             52     -4.917227269        -0.640765928        -1.226068432
O             54     -4.104085113         1.854234106       -16.404449463
O             56     -6.861676614        -0.640765928         4.845217687
O             58     -2.813776294         0.640765779         4.845217687
O             60     -5.076228778         0.640765779       -13.368642136
O             62     -7.020678123         0.640765779        -7.297355528
O             64     -0.869326828         0.640765779        -1.226068432
O             66     -2.023950100        -1.281531708         5.624757806
O             68     -4.286402584        -1.281531708       -12.589102506
O             70     -6.230851809        -1.281531708        -6.517815410
O             72     -0.079500634        -1.281531708        -0.446529291
O             74     -1.234123906         0.640765779         6.404297925
O             76     -3.496576390         0.640765779       -11.809563365
O             78     -5.441025615         0.640765779        -5.738276269
O             80      0.710325077         0.640765779         0.333010828
...           ...     ...........         ...........         ...........
```

I would like to concatenate these two files using the following pattern: C18 row follow by O34 row, then 3 rows out in the file 2: O42 row, and then another 3 rows out in file 2: O50 row.

Next, C20, O36, O44 and O52. As you may noticed, after 4 loops the pattern repeat O rows, so I want to jump to O58 row in C26 and following rows. The files are quite big so I just need something which jump after these 4 iterations. For clarity I will show you the output file:

```
cat file 3
C             18     -2.182951850        -0.000000000        -6.517815410 
O             34     -1.393125174        -0.640765928        -5.738276269
O             42     -2.182951850         1.281531856        -6.517815410
O             50     -2.972778044        -0.640765928        -7.297355528
C             20     -4.127401075         0.000000000        -0.446529291
O             36     -3.337574640        -0.640765928         0.333010828
O             44     -4.127401075         1.281531856        -0.446529291
O             52     -4.917227269        -0.640765928        -1.226068432
C             22     -3.314258919        -2.494999886       -15.624910016
O             38     -2.524270589         1.854234106       -14.845370570
O             46     -3.314258919        -1.213468178       -15.624910016
O             54     -4.104085113         1.854234106       -16.404449463
C             24     -6.071850300         0.000000000         5.624757806
O             40     -5.282024106        -0.640765928         6.404297925
O             48     -6.071850300         1.281531856         5.624757806
O             56     -6.861676614        -0.640765928         4.845217687
here comes the problem!!
C             26     -2.023950100         0.000000000         5.624757806
O             58     -2.813776294         0.640765779         4.845217687
O             66     -2.023950100        -1.281531708         5.624757806
O             74     -1.234123906         0.640765779         6.404297925
C             28     -4.286402584        -0.000000000       -12.589102506
O             60     -5.076228778         0.640765779       -13.368642136
O             68     -4.286402584        -1.281531708       -12.589102506
O             76     -3.496576390         0.640765779       -11.809563365
..             ..      ............        .............       .........
```

Here is the code I used when I want to have repeat O rows:

```
# first file
NR == FNR { 
    a[NR] = $0  # save each line into array
    ++len
    next        # skip further blocks
}

{ b[FNR] = $0 } # save each line from 2nd file into array

END {
    # loop through and print
    for (i = 1; i <= len; ++i) {
        print a[i]
        for (j = i; j <= FNR; j += 4) print b[j]
    }
}
```

and executing like `awk -f script.awk file1 file2`

Many thanks in advance.
Git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are large, in memory operations may not be feasible.  Here I would suggest a two stage approach.  Shuffle file2 rows in the same order to appear in desired format and merge file1 and file2 by 1:3 row ratio.

For example:

```
$ awk   '{a[(NR-1)%12]=$0} 
 NR%12==0{for(i=0;i<4;i++) 
            for(j=0;j<3;j++) 
               print a[i+j*4]; 
               delete a
         }' <(seq 1 24)
1
5
9
2
6
10
3
7
11
4
8
12
13
17
21
14
18
22
15
19
23
16
20
24
```

will put the file2 rows in the right order.  Combine with the merge

```
awk '{print; for(i=1;i<=3;i++) {getline x < "file2_reordered"; print x}}' file1
```

will give you the desired output.

ps. This row shuffling is similar to transposing a sequence of 3x4 matrices (take each row as an element).

UPDATE:  Thinking the problem the other way around, you can intersperse file1 contents while processing file2.  This will be a single script.

```
$ awk     '{a[(NR-1)%12]=$0} 
   NR%12==0{for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
               getline x < "file1"; print x; 
               for(j=0;j<3;j++) 
                   print a[i+j*4]
               } 
               delete a
           }' file2
C             18     -2.182951850        -0.000000000        -6.517815410
O             34     -1.393125174        -0.640765928        -5.738276269
O             42     -2.182951850         1.281531856        -6.517815410
O             50     -2.972778044        -0.640765928        -7.297355528
C             20     -4.127401075         0.000000000        -0.446529291
O             36     -3.337574640        -0.640765928         0.333010828
O             44     -4.127401075         1.281531856        -0.446529291
O             52     -4.917227269        -0.640765928        -1.226068432
C             22     -3.314258919        -2.494999886       -15.624910016
O             38     -2.524270589         1.854234106       -14.845370570
O             46     -3.314258919        -1.213468178       -15.624910016
O             54     -4.104085113         1.854234106       -16.404449463
C             24     -6.071850300         0.000000000         5.624757806
O             40     -5.282024106        -0.640765928         6.404297925
O             48     -6.071850300         1.281531856         5.624757806
O             56     -6.861676614        -0.640765928         4.845217687
C             26     -2.023950100         0.000000000         5.624757806
O             58     -2.813776294         0.640765779         4.845217687
O             66     -2.023950100        -1.281531708         5.624757806
O             74     -1.234123906         0.640765779         6.404297925
C             28     -4.286402584        -0.000000000       -12.589102506
O             60     -5.076228778         0.640765779       -13.368642136
O             68     -4.286402584        -1.281531708       -12.589102506
O             76     -3.496576390         0.640765779       -11.809563365
C             30     -6.230851809        -0.000000000        -6.517815410
O             62     -7.020678123         0.640765779        -7.297355528
O             70     -6.230851809        -1.281531708        -6.517815410
O             78     -5.441025615         0.640765779        -5.738276269
C             32     -0.079500634         0.000000000        -0.446529291
O             64     -0.869326828         0.640765779        -1.226068432
O             72     -0.079500634        -1.281531708        -0.446529291
O             80      0.710325077         0.640765779         0.333010828
```

Comment: looks great!! I will try this one. Thanks